# ionic + AngularJS erro list item

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic, lista

Fiz uma lista no ionic que retorna alguns valores, porem quando clico na lista para mostrar esses valores por completo, não estou conseguindo recuperar...

meu controller:

```
    app.factory('services', ['$http', function($http) {
    var obj={};
    obj.getPessoas = function() { return $http.get('http://xxxx.com.br/conecta.php'); }
    return obj;
}]);

app.controller("pessoasCtrl", function($scope, services,$ionicScrollDelegate) {
    services.getPessoas().then( function(data) {
        $scope.pessoas = data.data;
    } )

    $scope.scrollTop = function() {
        $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop(true);   
    }; 
})
```

meu app.js

```
.state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'pessoasCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'pessoasCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

A chamada na pagina chats:

```
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="pessoa in pessoas" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{pessoa.DOU_CODIGO}}">
        <img ng-src="{{pessoa.face}}">
        <h2>{{pessoa.DOU_NOME}}</h2>
        <p>{{chat.DOU_ESPECIALIDADE}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
```

e quando clico em cada linha, não consigo recupera no chat-detail que está assim:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{pessoa.DOU_CODIGO}}">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <img ng-src="{{pessoa.face}}" style="width: 64px; height: 64px">
    <p>
      {{pessoa.DOU_CODIGO}}
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não vi no seu controller onde você tenta resgatar o valor do ID que passou, geralmente usamos o `$stateParams.NomeDoparametro`. 
Eu faria da seguinte forma: Tiraria o href e chamaria uma função no ng-click

```
ng-click="selecionaPessoa(pessoa)"
```

Dessa forma vc passa todo o objeto selecionado, sem precisar fazer select novamente. Ai é só adicionar a pessoa ao scope dentro da função:

```
$scope.selecionaPessoa = function(pessoa){
    $scope.selecionado = pessoa;
};
```

No seu HTML é só chamar `{{selecionado.DOU_CODIGO}}`